# How should both a core team project and individual projects be handled with JIRA and the SCRUM method?

Tags: jira, scrum, kanban

**Summary**

We're a medium sized company that has a development team of five team members. We recently started learning/employing the SCRUM method to our R&D department.

Our core team has one project, while each employee has individual task and projects. Some of those individual projects are only big enough for a single developer to complete.

Additionally, a single developer may be supporting a product they released individually.

Furthermore, we currently use a JIRA SCRUM board to track our progress in our core team project, while we each use individual JIRA Kanban boards to handle our individual tasks/projects.

We found that it's easy to go over the core team's project during the sprint review, but it's difficult to have visibility into our daily tasks and projects not related to the core project.

Should we utilize a single Kanban board that pulls in all of our core teams SCRUM board issues, and all of our other non-core team tasks/projects?

Then we go over all issues in the all-inclusive Kanban board during our sprint review meeting? If so, how should we filter our Kanban board? Updated within a certain time frame, labels, etc...?

Or should we use a single SCRUM board and force the entire team to plan and estimate both the core team's project and all the individual tasks/projects? What happens when new support issues occur during the middle of the sprint? Do we adjust the sprint scope mid sprint?

**Question**

What method of grouping should we use to present both our core team's shared project, and each developer's individual tasks/projects while preserving SCRUM estimation and planning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about development process, not programming, so it should be on Software Engineering SE.

Comment: That's fine. I can move it. I"ll delete it myself.

Comment: You can also flag for moderator intervention to have them migrate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [project management is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343841) You can ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please close this issue. I've posted it in the appropriate forum. Apologies for posting this in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single board.

Why have separate projects for individuals?
Are you separating out support or are they specialized projects that only a single person can do?

Comment: They are specialize projects that only a single person can do. We know we need to make our teams more cross-functional and will have people shadow them, but for now we need that one individual to at least complete them individually.

Comment: Questions about project management are off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you might want to take your advice over to [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [ProjectManagement.SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/), where you can put your skills to use.

Comment: @Machavity could you please edit your template to refer "help/on-topic" links instead of sites home pages? See [this meta post from mod of one of these sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355052/839601) for reasons why this way is preferred